# Where can I find a download for SharePoint 2007 64bit language packs

Tags: sharepoint

Might sound like an easy question, but every single link I have found says the only OS it supports is Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2003 SP1.

So can someone please tell me where is the language pack for other server versions. For example Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: Have you tried the language packs on server 2008? It could be that the MS pages have just not been updated to show 2008 support

Comment: Yes tried them , even done the hack / extract method of changing the configuration.xml - nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the steps below to add multi-lingual support for SharePoint 2007. If you are running Service Pack 2 of SharePoint Server 2007 you only have to download the SP2 language packs. The SP2 language packs include all materials that are in the SP1 language packs. They will install on Windows Server 2008.

You must download both the Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 language packs and the Office SharePoint Server 2007 language packs.

1. Download WSS Language Packs RTM [ [32-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=36EE1BF0-652C-4E38-B247-F29B3EEFA048&displaylang=en) | [64-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=45FA2637-EFC0-4ED6-8F47-8A013E9CE9D9&displaylang=en) ]
2. Install the language packs you downloaded in step above (any order, it does not matter).
3. Make sure that you DO NOT RUN the SharePoint Configuration Wizard.
4. Download SharePoint/MOSS Language Packs RTM [ [32-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2447426B-8689-4768-BFF0-CBB511599A45&displaylang=en) | [64-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=318D8562-58BD-4329-B1F6-F1941A38BC7F&displaylang=en) ]
5. Install the language packs you downloaded in step above (any order, it does not matter).
6. Make sure that you DO NOT RUN the SharePoint Configuration Wizard.
7. Download WSS Language Packs SP2 [ [32-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=085e5ac8-58f6-4cf9-8012-33b95ee36c0f&displaylang=en) | [64-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2C2B6CAF-B46D-45EB-AC4D-DEAAA48C3A2C&displaylang=en) ]
8. Install the language packs you downloaded in step above (any order, it does not matter).
9. Make sure that you DO NOT RUN the SharePoint Configuration Wizard.
10. Download SharePoint/MOSS Language Packs SP2 [ [32-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1203DB2-1CC9-4809-9B6E-3F232CB8899F&displaylang=en) | [64-Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1203DB2-1CC9-4809-9B6E-3F232CB8899F&displaylang=en) ]
11. Install the language packs you downloaded in step above (any order, it does not matter).
12. When all are set to configure SharePoint/MOSS for multilingual support, so go ahead and run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard, which is simple, do not make any changes just accept the defaults presented. I assume that SharePoint farm was already configured. If this is a new Farm install then you need to follow normal setup guidelines for SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 0):

[Clicky](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=66c5026f-9f47-4642-8378-2526918009fa), seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Thats an SP to a language pack, not the language pack itself.

Comment: At the bottom of that page is a 'what others are downloading', one is http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=318D8562-58BD-4329-B1F6-F1941A38BC7F&displaylang=en you'l then be able to apply this service pack.

Comment: Yup - and read the link there - Supported Operating Systems: Windows Server 2003

Comment: And to make matters even more interesting the 64bit version as expected - Supported Operating Systems: Windows Server 2003 x64 editions

Comment: Oh well, done my best, I'd suggest you either call MS or trawl their site.

Comment: This is the frustration of a SharePoint developer :(